# Google analytics does not show any data in any dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I'm very new to google analytics. I'm using it to know the performance metrics of a website, this website is not mine. I'm assigned to analyze the performance metrics of that website. The step i do is i sign in, put the url to the website and then i'm directed to the home but somehow in every dashboard i check, there's no data at all. The website is `https://www.latihid.com/`.

I'm very confused right now because I thought simple sign in and putting link url is enough for the google analytics to show me the dashboards of the data and i have seen in every tutorial I found that when they open the google analytics it will show them the dashboard with data (not blank dashboards).

Please help me, what's wrong and how to fix it

Comment: it takes 48 - 72 hours for a new google analytics account to start showing data

Comment: although the website have been existed and operated for long time? @DaImTo

Comment: show an example of your Analytics report, pls.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## steps to begin using Google analytics.

1. Create account on google analytics
2. Add Tracking script to your website [JavaScript snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/)

## Account creation latency (1)

When you create a new google analytics account on the google analytics website it can take between 48 -72 hours for this account to start recording data.  This has nothing to do with the age of your website it has to do with the time it takes to prevision your account.

## Data processing latency (2)

Once your account is ready to start displaying data and you have added the [JavaScript snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/) to your website and have begun sending hits to Google
analytics.  If you check the real time reports on the Google analytics website you will begin seeing it recording data.

It takes 24 -48 hours for data sent to google analytics to complete processing and be shown in the standard reports.  Again this has nothing to do with your website it has to do with the data processing latency on Google analytics.